# NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification being called even though no internet connect

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I'm trying to setup iCloud on my app by following [Enabling iCloud Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3) from Apple. I have added an iCloud-Enabled Persistent Store to Core Data, and retrieved the required log messages.

I then removed my app and reinstalled it. My `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification` is called and so now I am up to the third part which is iCloud Performs One Time Setup and here is my code:

```
func subscribeToPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresNotifications() {

        // Subscribe for first time setup of iCloud
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "enableUI", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: sharedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: sharedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { notification in

            // First reset the managed object context
            self.sharedContext.performBlock() {
                print("=== RESETTING CONTEXT ===")
                self.sharedContext.reset()
            }

            // Then disable UI
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("=== DISABLING UI===")
                self.disableUI()
            }
        }
    }
```

I have just followed the template that Apple gave and this function is called in my `viewWillAppear` in the first View Controller that users see.

So then I followed Apple's setup and testing routines:

> Setup: On your iOS device, begin with airplane mode enabled. If you’re creating a Mac app, disable every network interface instead. Completely remove your app from your device as well.
>
> Test: Run your app and create a few records. Disable airplane mode or
>   reenable a network interface and wait for Core Data to print “Using
>   local storage: 0” to the console in Xcode. Core Data invokes your
>   notification handlers and your records disappear. In the next section
>   you’ll learn how to persist in-memory changes.

Every goes well until I start testing it, even though I start my app in Airplane mode I think somehow my iPhone is still able to connect to iCloud and as a result the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification` is being called.

**Note:** I have also tested it with data being stored in CoreData and then deleting the app when the data has been successfully uploaded to iCloud. When I reinstall the app in Airplane mode, I am still able to retrieve the stored data.

Any ideas?